# How to mount router-link outside app?

Tags: vue.js

I am using the basic tutorial of the [guide/Getting started](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/#html),  but changed HTML code to

```
<div id="app">
  <!-- ... all the same except router-view ... -->
</div>

<h2>Outside:</h2>
<code id="outApp"><router-view></router-view></code>
```

But, of course, it is not working, I need to say to mount `router-view` at `#outApp`, how to do it?

PS: when `#outApp` is inside `#app`  all is working fine, on my page reproduction of tutorial.

Comment: Just don't do it. You'll end up including it inside #app sooner or later because what you're doing is not a good practice.

Comment: Hi @Frondor, I agree about "good practice", but sometimes we need to use complex HTML structures, and a simple arrangement is not possible, need to use links and templates into (many) different places.

Comment: Then you'll need to instantiate a new Vue instance and use the router view in there

Comment: @Frondor ...hum... can I do similar thing using [modules](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/modules.html)?  Independent-logic modules, but one publishing `router-view` in another.

Comment: Peter, that's a vuex feature, not vue.js. Vuex is just a plugin to implement the flux pattern in Vue apps. You just need another `new Vue({ el: '#app2' })`

Comment: worth noting that in Vue3 the Teleport component should allow this to work out of the box. https://vuejs.org/guide/built-ins/teleport.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As commented previously, and being sure you're already notified about this *unpractical practice's*. This is the solution I offer you.

Create a new `Vue` instance (`#app2`) and use the router in there.

```js
Vue.config.productionTip = Vue.config.devtools = false // ignore
const router = new VueRouter({
  routes: [
{
  path: "/",
  component: { template: "<router-view/>" },
  children: [
    {
      path: "",
      name: "foo",
      component: { template: "<div>Foo</div>" }
    },
    {
      path: "bar",
      name: "bar",
      component: { template: "<div>Bar</div>" }
    }
  ]
}
  ]
});

// App1 without routing capabilities
new Vue({
  // router, don't need it here
  el: "#app1"
});

// App2
new Vue({
  router,
  el: "#app2"
});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.16"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-router/dist/vue-router.js"></script>

<fieldset>
  <legend>App1</legend>
  <div id="app1">
This is the app without router
  </div>
</fieldset>

<fieldset>
  <legend>App2</legend>
  <div id="app2">
<router-link :to="{name:'foo'}">Foo</router-link>
<router-link :to="{name: 'bar'}">Bar</router-link>
<hr>
<router-view></router-view>
  </div>
</fieldset>
```